Twilio voice goes immediately from ringing to completed
Twilio voice call would immediately complete almost instantly. I know there is a similar question with accepted answer but not entirely revelant to my case and answer doesn't work.
Here are a few things I have tried:

Tried including the recipient number in callDevice?.connect(). Adding this would include the number in the To field for only ringing webhook event received.
Tried not including dial.number(+2_RECEIPT_NUMBER);.

Webhook & XML
Here is what the ringing webhook received looks like:
{
    ApplicationSid: 'APP_SID',
    ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
    Called: '',
    Caller: 'client:+13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO',
    CallStatus: 'ringing',
    From: 'client:+13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO',
    CallSid: 'CALL_SID',
    To: '', //would be present if number is included in the call.connect.
    Direction: 'inbound',
    AccountSid: 'MY_ACCOUNT_SID'
}

I would send an XML that looks like this in reponse:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Response><Dial callerId="+13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO"><Number>+2_RECEIPT_NUMBER</Number></Dial></Response>

Then a completed is receved:
{
    ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
    Called: '',
    CallStatus: 'completed',
    Duration: '0',
    From: 'client:+ 13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO',
    Direction: 'inbound',
    CallDuration: '0',
    Timestamp: 'Sat, 14 Dec 2024 19:06:32 +0000',
    AccountSid: 'MY_ACCOUNT_SID',
    CallbackSource: 'call-progress-events',
    ApplicationSid: 'APP_SID',
    Caller: 'client:+13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO',
    SequenceNumber: '0',
    CallSid: 'CallSid',
    To: ''
}

Code sample:
Here is what my code looks like:

I first generate a token this way:

const twilioAccountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
        const twilioApiKey = process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY;
        const twilioApiSecret = process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET;

        // Used specifically for creating Voice tokens
        const outgoingApplicationSid = "APP_SID";
        // const identity = 'user';

        // Create a "grant" which enables a client to use Voice as a given user
        const voiceGrant = new VoiceGrant({
            outgoingApplicationSid: outgoingApplicationSid,
            incomingAllow: true, // Optional: add to allow incoming calls
        });

        // Create an access token which we will sign and return to the client,
        // containing the grant we just created
        const token = new AccessToken(
            twilioAccountSid,
            twilioApiKey,
            twilioApiSecret,
            { identity: `+13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO ` }
        );
        token.addGrant(voiceGrant);

        // Serialize the token to a JWT string
        const tokenJWT = token.toJwt()
        console.log(tokenJWT);
        return tokenJWT

Then with the return JWT token, I would create a device, and connect call:
 const handleCall = async (phoneNumber) => {
        // return toast.error(`You can't dial a number yet`)
        const params = { To: phoneNumber };
        callDevice?.emit("connect");
        callDevice
            ?.connect()
            // ?.connect({
            //     params: params,
            //     rtcConstraints: {
            //         audio: true,
            //     },
            // })
            .then((call) => {
                setCallInstance(call)
                call.on("accept", () => {
                    setConnection(connection);
                    setUserState(USER_STATE.ON_CALL);
                    console.log("call accepted");
                });
                call.on("disconnect", () => {
                    console.log("The call has been disconnected.");
                    setUserState(USER_STATE.READY);
                    setConnection(null);
                });
                call.on("reject", () => {
                    console.log("The call was rejected.");
                });
            });
    };

Then for the webhook used in TwiML, I have:

                const { ApplicationSid, ApiVersion, Called, Caller, CallStatus, From, To, CallSid, Direction, AccountSid } = req.body

                console.log({ ...req.body })
                if (CallStatus === "ringing" || CallStatus === "initiated") {
                    const client = new VoiceResponse.twiml.VoiceResponse();
                    const dial = client.dial({ callerId: `+13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO ` });
                    dial.number(`+2_RECEIPT_NUMBER`);
                    // dial.number({
                    //     statusCallbackEvent: 'initiated ringing answered in-progress completed',
                    //     statusCallback: 'https://myapp.com/calls/events',
                    //     statusCallbackMethod: 'POST'
                    // }, '+12349013030');
                    const clientXML = client.toString()
                    console.log({ clientXML })
                    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
                    res.send(clientXML);
                }
                if (CallStatus === "in-progress") {
                    // Twilio credentials

                    const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

                    const call = await client.calls(CallSid).fetch();

                    const price = parseFloat(call.price || 0);
                    const priceUnit = call.priceUnit;
                    const duration = call.duration;
                    console.log({ price, priceUnit, duration })
                }

                if (CallStatus === 'completed') {
                    const client = twilio(accountSid, authToken);

                    const call = await client.calls(CallSid).fetch();

                    const price = parseFloat(call.price || 0);
                    const priceUnit = call.priceUnit;
                    const duration = call.duration;
                    console.log({ price, priceUnit, duration })

                    // await saveCallCostToDatabase({
                    //     callSid: CallSid,
                    //     totalCost: price,
                    //     duration: duration
                    // });
                }

                if (CallStatus === 'canceled') {

                }

                if (CallStatus === 'busy') {

                }

                if (CallStatus === 'failed') {

                }

            

Expected behavior:

The call rings on the recipient phone, +2_RECEIPT_NUMBER, after the XML response was sent to twilio.
An in-progress webhook is received once the recipient picks up.
A completed webhook is received when the call ends.

According to the Twilio doc here, there should be a ring at my destination number and completed calls incur charges. Neither of these happened, making it all the more confusing.
+13NUMBER_FROM_TWLIO is twilio's provided number.
+2_RECEIPT_NUMBER is the number I am trying to call.
Been at this all day, any help will be greatly appreciated.
